# Node Feathers Sequelize API invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I am setting up an API to a SQL Server 2008 database using Node, Feathers and Sequelize. I have successfully created the models and services using feathers-sequelize-auto, and most of the routes seem to be working. The app runs but with an error message:

```
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  {"_bitField":18087936,"_fulfillmentHandler0":{}}
```

I'm getting an error for one of the routes (/project) relating to one of its foreign keys. Postman output for /project is:

```
{
    "name": "GeneralError",
    "message": "Invalid column name 'OrganisationID'.",
    "code": 500,
    "className": "general-error",
    "data": {},
    "errors": {}
}
```

All works fine in the database itself, and I can run queries on the related tables with no issues.

Relevant parts of the Project.model.js:

Field definitions

```
LeadAgency: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: 'Organisation',
          key: 'OrganisationID'
        }
```

Relationships:

```
Project.associate = function(models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    Project.belongsTo(models.Team, { foreignKey: 'TeamID' });
    Project.belongsTo(models.Subteam, { foreignKey: 'SubTeamID' });
    Project.belongsTo(models.Staff, { foreignKey: 'StaffID' });
    Project.belongsTo(models.Organisation, { foreignKey: 'OrganisationID' });
    Project.belongsTo(models.Project, { foreignKey: 'ProjectID' });
  };
```

And this is the Organisation.model.js code:

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

// See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/
// for more of what you can do here.

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function(app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const Organisation = sequelizeClient.define(
    'Organisation',
    {
      OrganisationID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      Name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      Type: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
      },
      AddressID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: 'Address',
          key: 'AddressID'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: 'Organisation',
      timestamps: false
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        }
      }
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  Organisation.associate = function(models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    Organisation.belongsTo(models.Address, { foreignKey: 'AddressID' });
  };

  return Organisation;
};
```

Noob here so could be missing something obvious. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error due to incorrect mappings in model.associate. In your Project model you have defined `Project` as associate also. This can be the reason.